# Is there a general algorithm for determining if two nodes in a graph rejoin at a common point?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph with certain rules: all nodes are members of a path, and a node may have at most two edges to other nodes, and the final node in a path is detectable. There may be cycles, but in the case of a cycle, there is always at least one edge out of the cycle.

The requirements of the output are that, if A has two edges that rejoin at B, regardless of whether B has different termination points, then A is said to rejoin at B. Along each path from A to B, there may be more than one split. A rejoins at B only if each split along either path to B also always reaches B. So the algorithm must recursively keep track of the status of nodes as it descends to other nodes.

I was thinking what would simplify my algorithm is using something like the [leaderlist algorithm](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/Leaderlist.html) to contract nodes with less than 2 egress edges into one. Each time a given node is recognized as having rejoined at another, it is contracted into a common node, with the egress point and the final rejoin point retained in a map.

Is there a simple algorithm with good complexity that could run on the output of leaderlist to return a map of edges and their rejoin points?

Comment: To be clear, both `A` and `B` are inputs to the problem?

Comment: Well, no actually; map[A]=B would be a part of the output though. A is the node with two edges, B is the point where each path along those edges all finally rejoin. 

The input is the entire graph, and the algorithm should return the map without editing the graph.

Comment: Ah, so the input is just the graph `G`, and you want every pair of points `(A,B)` that rejoin

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Are you looking for something faster than `O(mn)` where `n` is the number of vertices and `m` is the number of edges? In fact, since there are at most 2 outgoing edges, `m = O(n)` and the time complexity would be `O(n^2)`, which would not be difficult to achieve. I would have thought that this is fast enough in most cases?

Comment: I know all the nodes that have two edges, so the analysis can start from one of these each time. 

O(n) is fine, the reverse tree data structure that I explained in the question would have achieved this running time, although with O(n) space. I'd be curious to know how to keep that O(n) time without the space, if you have that.

In my case, adapting that data structure to the graph case kind of would make for a difficult programming problem, but it's doable. I just would prefer to reuse an existing solution. I thought perhaps graph coloring was more general, and could be specialized.